# Loop through tr's with Jquery and compare contents with next row in series

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm somewhat new to jQuery/javascript, and would like to compare the contents of `row[i]` in a table body with `row[i+1]`.

Is this something I can do with jQuery or should I just use plain old JS and `getElementByid` and then loop that way? using the `.each` doesn't appear to give anyway of accessing the next element in the series easily.

I assume if/when I find a solution to this, I then need to figure out how to compare `row[i].td[j]` to `row[i+1].td[j]`.

I imagine this is simple, but my searches so far have come up with null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my full solution so far involves something along these lines:

```
  function myfunc(table) {
    $(table).each(function(i,n) {
      var current = $(n);
      var next = $(table).eq(i+1);
      if (next.length) {
        current.children().each(function(a,b) {
          var current_td = $.trim($(b).text());
          var next_td = $.trim(next.children().eq(a).text());
          /* compare here */
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

note that `next` may end up being an empty jquery object if you're at the last `tr`

```
var trs = $('tr');
trs.each(function(i,n) {
    var current = $(n);
    var next = trs.eq(i+1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the previous element and do the compare on the 'next':

```
        var callback = (function() {
            var lastTr;

            return (function(i, n) {
                if (lastTr) {
                    //logic $(this) is 'next', lastTr is 'current'
                }

                lastTr = $(this);
            });
        })();;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('tr').each(callback); 
        });
```